# MVVM Получить View в View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня имеется окно авторизации: TextBox для логина, PasswordBox для пароля и кнопочка - Войти. После того как пользователь вводит данные мне нужно проверить их и закрыть окно. Используя Command и CommandParameter я делаю это все в View Model передавая туда окно через интерфейс. Правильно ли из точки зрения MVVM работать с View из View Model?

Answer (score 0):

View должна подписываться на VievModel -- на обьекты, события или вызов методов. По факту они не должны знать про реализации одна другой.

Если ты в VievModel обращаешся к конкретному обьекту/контролу твоего View -- то это уже неправильно.

VievModel должна быть отвязана от конкретного View и быть в достаточной мере универсальной что бы можно было заменить View на другой (например WPF окно на экран мобильного телефона) без изменений или же с минимальными изменениями.

Comment: и каким образом мне тогда закрыть окно?

Comment: Например так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172462/close-window-from-viewmodel . Как видишь из принятого ответа, там нету привязки к конкретному окну. Так же можно поизучать вот эту линку: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form/2100824#2100824

Comment: Кстате, для описанного случая вторая линка, даже, будет лучше.